# cPanel/WHM not writing to server

Tags: linux

In WHM when I edit any settings it will modify it in WHM but it will not write the changes to the servers.

Ex. I am configuring the nameserver IP addresses in WHM but when I look at the file where it is stored on the server the fields are blank and the changes were not made. WHM will show they were made tho, so I have to edit the files directly instead of using WHM.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `How can I fix this issue?`  Unfortunately, after a cPanel infection, your only option is to format the disk and start fresh.

Comment: I'm afraid it's hard to answer your question without some more detail. Please can you have a look at: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Open a ticket with CPanel support.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I fix this issue?

Ditch cPanel and commit to learning CLI administration.

Honestly.

In addition to causing issues like this, these GUI control panels enable you to be blissfully ignorant of how your system actually works, preventing you from learning the skills necessary to configure, secure, troubleshoot, and properly maintain your system.

My opinion (and that which is shared with many other professional sysadmins) is that GUI control panels are a **user's** tool, not a **sysadmin's** tool and as such, the vast majority of cPanel questions are off-topic for Serverfault.

Comment: This is for a "users" server. They came to me with this issue and I just replicated it. I performed what needed to be done using SSH but the client would like this fixed. So I can't ditch cPanel since my clients are using it, not myself.

Comment: Then you're stuck with going through cPanel support. That's what your client is paying for and honestly, there's so little experience here with cPanel (due to the above reasons) that you'll get a better answer to your question elsewhere.